# Installing a package with both conda and pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

If I've installed a python package using both conda and pip then when I call a function from that package, will I be using the version from conda or from pip?

My situation is as follows: I'm trying to use the `from_estimator` method released in [scikit-learn version 1.0.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v1.0.html) this past September. However, my current version of scikit-learn was version 0.24.2 so I decided to update the package. I previously had installed conda, but never actually used it to update/install a package; instead I always used pip. This time I decided to try to install scikit-learn version 1.0 with conda. However, when I wrote `conda install scikit-learn=1.0` in terminal, I got the error

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - scikit-learn=1.0
```

Frustrated, I decided to simply install scikit-learn version 1.0 with pip by typing `pip install -U scikit-learn` in terminal. This gave me the message

```
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /home/eturok/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.24.2)
Collecting scikit-learn
  Downloading scikit_learn-1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (23.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 23.1 MB 17.2 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/eturok/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1.0 in /home/eturok/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.6 in /home/eturok/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/eturok/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (2.2.0)
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Attempting uninstall: scikit-learn
    Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.24.2
    Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.24.2:
      Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.24.2
Successfully installed scikit-learn-1.0
```

Now typing `pip list` and `conda list` in terminal returns `scikit-learn 1.0` and `scikit-learn 1.0 pypi_0 pypi` respectively.

My questions are:

1. If I only updated scikit-learn with pip, why is scikit-learn also updated with conda?
2. Why at the beginning was I unable to update scikit-learn with conda? This version of scikit-learn was released pretty recently. Is it possible that conda hasn't yet gotten around to supporting the new release of scikit-learn yet?
3. In general, how does conda decide which packages to support?
4. If I've installed a python package using both conda and pip then when I call a function from that package, will I be using the version from conda or from pip?

Comment: Please keep it to one question per (StackOverflow) Question. And, BTW, you have multiple legitimate questions, so ask them all and reap the points for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not a conda expert, but since no one is bothering to answer:

1. I don't think it was. You got an error and installation was aborted. Might it be that `conda list` just sees the pip installed package and reports it as comming from `pypi`?
2. Yes, conda default repo for scikit-learn does not have 1.0 yet, 0.24 is the last (see here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scikit-learn). The conda-forge repo for scikit learn does have 1.0 (see here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scikit-learn)
3. I don't know how packages move from conda-forge to conda. Probably you should always use conda forge as in `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn`. Or, even better, always use `pip`.
4. No idea, don't do it :) Always use either conda or venv virtual environments and in such cases burn them with fire and start anew.